# Is it allowed/recommended to use height in responsive websites?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I saw somewhere that it wasn't recommended to use height and use padding instead, why that? The height and the padding produces the same results - at least in my trials -... is there a reason for me be to be using padding only instead of height?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, there are many reasons to use height instead of padding, but it depends on what you're doing. If someone says "There is never a reason to use height" then they are wrong. What's the specific situation?

Comment: Just following up with what James Hay said, it's absolutely okay to use height in responsive websites.

Comment: Actually there's no specific situation, I'm trying to look for a reason to don't use height and use padding instead. - The thing is that I don't see a reason because mobile has the touch and the vertical scrolls.

Comment: Using any `foo` in any `bar` where that `foo` does not harm `bar` is allowed and there is no problem with using it.

Comment: @sємsєм - Nice example, I will quote it someday. ;) - Thank you all, I think that it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - of course you can use height in responsive websites without a problem.

I think where you may have read about using padding in place of height is for keeping the aspect ratio of an element the same since percentage based padding is relative to the width of the element and percentage based height is relative to it's container.

A common use case for this is embedding a YouTube video in a responsive wesbite.

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
   <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/k_d5jWvBirU?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=2&amp;autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/84wm08k7/

As you can see the height of the `video-container` is set to `0` and the `padding-bottom` is set to `56.25%`. This restricts this element to being a 16:9 aspect ratio for video and is responsive.

Comment: Really on the point. The key issue is that a percentage in *vertical* padding is related to an *horizontal* dimensiion. That oddity makes posible to make aspect-ratio constant.

Answer (score 0):

well to start if you use padding then the page will stretch itself to fit the screen leaving the given amount of border (padding). If you use a specified height (in pixels per say) the page will always be the same height regardless the resolution of the screen. If you are using height as a percentage or some analogous value, than it shouldn't matter other than that the amount of space (padding) will vary depending on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing. For a lot of my work, I'll set a min-height or max-height that way the element grows or shrinks depending on the content.

Padding would work as well, if for instance you have an element with text that would be centered vertically, you can use padding to control height as well. It's all up to the site design, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -3):

this is a code example you can check w3schools.com for further information, I've chosen the example in which you can manipulate the dom

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.height = "50px";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Change the height of this button</button>



</body>
</html>
```